# Databound Value in href javascript link

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net

I've trawled the net looking for the syntax to get this working and i'm hoping this is a quick fix else i'll go mad.  Basically I have a nested repeater and the button below hides another nested repeater.

`((location_details)((RepeaterItem)Container.Parent.Parent).DataItem).tbl_location.location_id` evaluates perfectly well (3824 in the case i'm testing), but when I try to pass it so that its a string parameter for the javascript function it fails everytime.

```
<asp:Linkbutton ID="lb_showhide_oloc_gnotes" runat="server" Text="Expand/Close" 
 href='javascript:sltoggle('" + <%# ((location_details)((RepeaterItem)Container.Parent.Parent).DataItem).tbl_location.location_id %> +" '); return false;' />
```

Any ideas what i'm missing (I know the above syntax is wrong I must have changed it 100 times already but you get the idea).

thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried `asp:HyperLink` and `NavigateUrl`? 
I think `asp:LinkButton` renders to an anchor tag and its `href` attribute should be generated by ASP (so it results in a postback) and that's why it won't bind to it.

Comment: I don't know if you need that server control in code behind but if you don't then you might just want to go: `<a href='javascript:sltoggle("<%= ((location_details)((RepeaterItem)Container.Parent.Parent).DataItem).tbl_location.location_id %>"); return false;'>Expand/Close</a>`

Comment: you are... a lifesaver.  With a bit of tinkering I managed to get it done:  heres the finished code :-

`<asp:HyperLink ID="lb_showhide_oloc_gnotes" runat="server" Text="Expand/Close" NavigateUrl='<%# "javascript: sltoggle(" + ((location_details)((RepeaterItem)Container.Parent.Parent).DataItem).tbl_location.location_id + ");return false;" %>' />`

Answer (score 0):

I can't test this right now so this might be wrong, but you don't need to concatenate the value of `href` together.

```
<asp:Linkbutton ID="lb_showhide_oloc_gnotes" runat="server" Text="Expand/Close" 
 href='javascript:sltoggle("<%# ((location_details)((RepeaterItem)Container.Parent.Parent).DataItem).tbl_location.location_id %>"); return false;' />
```

Comment: Hi, unfortunately in this instance when I try fire it on the page the link hasn't evaluated it properly.  So instead of sltoggle('3824');return false;    it still reads sltoggle("<%# ((loc...  etc

Am I missing something about the way it binds data in links? everything else seems to work everywhere else :(

Comment: Just noticed: why are you using `asp:LinkButton`? If you want to control the href, use `asp:Hyperlink`.